# Call outer function inside Backbone.js's View initialize method

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Inside Backbone.js's View I have initialize and fillTerminal functions like

```
fillTerminal: function() {
    // something to print
},
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('change:attr', function(styleProperty, styleValue) {
        // here I want to call fillTerminal function
    });
}
```

I tried like `fillTerminal()` and `this.fillTerminal(`) but without success. What is solution to this ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass in the context of "this" when you bind in this case.  You can read more about the context parameter here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events

```js
fillTerminal:function(){
    //something to print
},

initialize : function() {
    this.model.bind('change:attr', function(styleProperty, styleValue) {

        // here I want to call fillTerminal function
        this.fillTerminal();

    }, this);
}
```